Steam API: Get discount end date for a game with using its appID
I'm creating a Discord bot to post free games and I'm looking for an API endpoint that can give me the end date of a discount on a game. I've looked everywhere and haven't found a concrete answer, but the I'm 100% sure the data is available somewhere. https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids= does not provide this data on the games I've tried. https://store.steampowered.com/api/featuredcategories/ does have games with discount_expiration, but not 100% discount games.
